# Creation of an RPG.stackexchange flyer

Tags: discussion

I have been thinking about ways to increase our visibility to people who would be interested in our site. One thing that would be nifty would be flyer of some kind that would point people  here that we could post in our local gaming stores (I know ours has a corkboard for this sort of thing).

Could we create an official RPG.stackexchange flyer, with a QR code and such to lead them here?

Comment: 1. Word/OpenOffice; 2. http://qrcode.kaywa.com/; 3. ???; 4. Profit! --- Seriously, we don't even have a final design yet, so any "official" flyer would likely be community-brewn anyway.

Comment: I know [Parenting also has flyers](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers). This isn't unheard of (flyers for a beta site) but we prefer the offerings our users make. They are often pretty fsking cool. :D Heck, we have a [Graphic Design site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com). Pop into their chat, see if some of them wouldn't mind lending a hand. :)

Comment: @Aarthi any chance some of the art Jin previewed for our design (see our chat logs) might be made available for a fan created flyer?

Answer (score 3):

I can provide the graphics and design the flyer but I need some copy text. the [parenting flyer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-questions-should-we-put-on-a-rpg-se-flyer) had some interesting questions and urls on it. If you could give me the content then this is definitely doable!

Comment: we are on it! http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-questions-should-we-put-on-a-rpg-se-flyer

Answer (score 1):

I think doing so would definitely be possible, and to follow the lead set by [parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers) we need to pick out some exemplary questions to entice people.