# What questions should we put on a RPG.SE Flyer?

Tags: discussion

I think the best thing to put on a flyer for this site is questions. These would be exemplary questions that sound interesting to people, similar to the ones that [parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers) has:
[image]

In the format:
Question,
Image,
Tear off slips + QR code.

Comment: The [faq](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq) and [votes](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) tabs of the questions list may be a good place to start, although they're both a little bit polluted.

Comment: @AceCalhoon I've started picking form my favourited questions.

Comment: Make sure that whatever questions you pick *look awesome!* These are going to be the first questions that potential new users see when they click through. Make *sure* they're edited to be the best that they can be!

Comment: +1 for promoting parenting.se!

Comment: I like how the ones from PARENTING.SE have two different designs. Perhaps we should do the same. I can imagine having one design/image each for sci-fi (spaceship?), fantasy (dragon?), gothic/horror (vampire?), comic/superhero (superman?), modern (soldier with rifle?), as well as a neutral one (map with dice?) for GM-focused questions. I think showing that RPG.SE caters to lots of different styles, settings and games would be a good idea.

Comment: quick q. should we link all the questions in this thread for easy reference? or questions that gets more than 5 votes?

Comment: More than 5 votes sounds good.

Comment: Hey all how about you link the questions you're referencing - some of them are clear but some I'm not sure map to a real question.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12521/is-my-dm-a-killjoy-or-am-i-just-a-whining-player

Should go in too.

Comment: Could people post some of the flyers they make here, so other people can print & use them as well?

Answer (score 9):

[Total Party Kill - What do I do as a GM?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/933/2788)

Answer (score 8):

[How many people does it take to steal an Imperial Star Destroyer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7960/2788)

Answer (score 7):

[How do I get my PCs to not be a bunch of murderous cretins?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8002/2788)

Answer (score 5):

[Who created the idea of Experience Points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/who-created-the-idea-of-experience-points)

This seems like an intriguing historical question.

Answer (score 3):

**Can my Hacker have an army of robots?**

That sounds particularly awesome!

Answer (score 2):

What tools are useful to organize a GM's campaign notes?

Answer (score 1):

Tips for organising a short campaign?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question, but as it's a motto/tagline *it just fits so well*

**[The internet equivalent of a shining tower full of wizened sages and interstellar rules-lawyer robots. And we're here to help.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/2788)**

And I've love to see it on a flyer!

Answer (score 1):

We seem to be short on player-centric questions. Here's one:

[How can I play dumb?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/how-can-i-play-dumb)

Comment: I might need to change the name so it works better on a flyer; at the moment it doesn't have any link to roleplaying, unless we get a picture of a big dumb paladin on there maybe?

Comment: @Pureferret It probably wouldn't work with the format used by the Parenting flyer, but if we had RPG branding on it, it'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What should I do as a player to prepare for a gaming convention?

Answer (score 0):

What is the effect of a different probability curve?

Answer (score 0):

How can I enhance both my GM and player skills?