# Making a presence at PAX

Tags: discussion

After thinking about [Creation of an RPG.stackexchange flyer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1288/2922) and [What questions should we put on a RPG.SE Flyer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1292/2922) it got me thinking about PAX. For those of you who do not know, PAX is Penny Arcade Expo an event held twice a year (PAX East in Boston and PAX Prime in Seattle) and is host to over 10,000 gamers each.

PAX East is 63 days away at the time of this writing 2/2/2012. PAX Prime is in late August. Do we have any RPG.SE folks going to PAX East? Can we get something together for them to get our name out there? PAX has an entire section just for table top games, and many many big named companies make a show there. I think we would be terribly remiss is we ignored this opportunity.

Comment: Related: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1224/2788

Comment: Missed that one :D

Comment: If anyone plans on going to either PAX, I can try to make getting an RPG design finalized for swag purposes a priority. We will gladly provide anyone going to these shows with plenty of RPG.SE stuff to hand out.